# Unsure on how to show the featured page as my homepage

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I am creating a Ghost Theme and I want to have my `index.hbs` show the featured post as the page. I have tried a range of things but nothing seems to work:

**index.hbs**

```
{{!< default}}
{{!-- The tag above means: insert everything in this file
into the {body} of the default.hbs template --}}


{{!-- The main content area --}}
<main>
{{#foreach posts}}
  {{#has featured="true"}}
      {{post}}
  {{/has}}
{{/foreach}}
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve having a featured post as the main page would be to use [Dynamic Routing](https://ghost.org/docs/api/v3/handlebars-themes/routing/) and route `/` to the post or page with featured flag. Alternatively, you could fetch and display the featured post using the `{{get}}` query described [here](https://ghost.org/docs/api/v3/handlebars-themes/helpers/get/).